# What's wrong with my jQuery Validation?

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using the following jQuery Validat Function:

```
$("#mitgliedHinzufuegen").validate({
    ignore: ".ignore",
invalidHandler: function(e, validator){
    if(validator.errorList.length){
    $('#myTab a[href="#' + jQuery(validator.errorList[0].element).closest(".tab-pane").attr('id') + '"]').tab('show');
    $('#myTab a[href="#' + jQuery(validator.errorList[1].element).closest(".tab-pane").attr('id') + '"]').tab('show');

   }
},
    rules: {
        required: {
            required: true
        },
        vorname: {
            required:{                
                depends: function(element){
                    return $("#zahlungsart option:selected").val() != 'INT';
                }
            }
        },
        nachname: {
            required:{                
                depends: function(element){
                    return $("#zahlungsart option:selected").val() != 'INT';
                }
            }
        },
        plz: {
            required:{                
                depends: function(element){
                    return $("#zahlungsart option:selected").val() != 'INT';
                }
            }
        },
        ort: {
            required:{                
                depends: function(element){
                    return $("#zahlungsart option:selected").val() != 'INT';
                }
            }
        },
        adresse: {
            required:{                
                depends: function(element){
                    return $("#zahlungsart option:selected").val() != 'INT';
                }
            }
        },
        email: {
            required: false,
            email: true
        },
        geburtsdatum: {
            required:{                
                depends: function(element){
                    return $("#zahlungsart option:selected").val() != 'INT';
                }
            }
        },
        beitrag: {

            number: true,
            required:{                
                depends: function(element){
                    return $("#zahlungsart option:selected").val() != 'INT';
                }
            }
        },
        verlaengerung: {
            required:{                
                depends: function(element){
                    return $("#zahlungsart option:selected").val() != 'INT';
                }
            }
        },
        vertragsdauer: {
            required:{                
                depends: function(element){
                    return $("#zahlungsart option:selected").val() != 'INT';
                }
            }
        },
        zeiteinheit: {
            required:{                
                depends: function(element){
                    return $("#zahlungsart option:selected").val() != 'INT';
                }
            }
        },
        name_inhaber: {
            required:{                
                depends: function(element){
                    return $("#zahlungsart option:selected").val() != 'INT';
                }
            }
        },
        name_kto: {
            required:{                
                depends: function(element){
                    return $("#zahlungsart option:selected").val() != 'INT';
                }
            }
        },
        iban_kto: {
            minlength: 22,
            maxlength: 22,
            required:{                
                depends: function(element){
                    return $("#zahlungsart option:selected").val() == 'L';
                },
            },
        },
        bic_kto: {
            minlength: 8,
            maxlength: 12,
            required:{                
                depends: function(element){
                    return $("#zahlungsart option:selected").val() == 'L';
                },
            },
         },
    },
    errorClass: "help-inline",
    errorElement: "span",
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
    }
});
```

First time i am submitting the form, it works fine. But as soon as I add a value to the "iban_kto" the "bic_kto" goes green too even if there's no input ... What is wrong with my code?

Thanks
skizZ

Comment: can you edit [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CLnEE/1/) to recreate the issue - add your html and css

Comment: It'll be pretty hard because i'm using a bootstrap template...

Comment: Hmm, that works, you can add it on the left.